# Amdroid app: Video player app

Tags: android

I am making a video player app. Lets make myself clear in this app no video or audio files will be saved in the raw directory during making the app. I want an app that will pick a video file from device storage when clicked a button. So please help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is "how do I write this?", please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: I've written code in Android Studio which plays videos which are stored already in raw directory of the apk, I want to pick video to play at the runtime of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options for allowing the user to pick a video, including:

- Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` on Android 4.4+. You will get a `Uri` back that you can pass to `VideoView` or `MediaPlayer`.
- Use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Again, you will get a `Uri` back that you can pass to `VideoView` or `MediaPlayer`.
- Use [a third-party file picker library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created). Depending on the library, I would expect you to get a `File` or a `Uri` back for use with your video player.

The first two techniques are covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html), along with good books on Android app development.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: My app is picking videos at runtime by clicking button but not playing the video giving an alert message "Can't play the video".
onClick:-button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent galleryIntent=new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setType("video/*");
                galleryIntent.setAction(galleryIntent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent,"Select Video"),9);

            }
        });

Comment: onActivityResult:-
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==9 && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri videoUri=data.getData();
            videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
            videoView.start();
        }
    }

Comment: @RaviPrakash: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide your current code, the value of the `Uri` that you are trying, and any stack traces that you are getting from this in LogCat.